# Proving an equation for the number of "sentences" using $k$ letters

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose there is a language of three words $W_1=a$, $W_2=ba$, $W_3=bb$. Let $N(k)$ be the number of sentences using exactly $k$ letters. Then there is only one sentence with a single letter, $(a)\,$ so $N(1) = 1$. Furthermore, $N(2) = 3$ since there are three possible sentences with two letters: ($a.a/ ba/ bb$). Also $N(3) = 5$, with the possible sentences being $(a.a.a/ a.ba/ ba.a/ a.bb/ bb.a)$. No space is allowed between words.

I'm trying to show that
$$(*)\quad\quad  N(k) = N(k-1) + 2N(k-2),\,\,k=2,3\ldots,$$ where $N(0)=1$.

I'm going to use a combinatorial argument, but before that, I just want to check $(*)$ is correct for some $k$.

For instance, if $k=4$, $(*)$ implies $N(4) = N(3)+2N(2)=5+2\cdot 3=11$, i.e. there are 11 four-letter sentences. However, as far as I can see, the possible four-letter sentences are
$$(a.a.a.a/ a.a.ba/ a.ba.a/ ba.a.a/ a.a.bb/ a.bb.a/ bb.a.a/ ba.bb/ bb.ba),$$
9 and not 11 as $(*)$ predicts.

I must be missing something...

Comment: Well...there are meant to be $N(2)=3$ sentences ending in $ba$, what are they?  They are $aaba, bbba,baba$.  You are missing $baba$.  I'd continue in that spirit.

Comment: Side note:  I don't know that it's a great idea to write the sentences as words.  In principle there could be some confusion (though I don't think that's possible in this particular case).  If you had words $b,bb,bbb$ then how could we interpret the sentence $bbbb$?

Comment: I belive the original choice of the "words" is studied to avoid the possibility of confusion you point out.

Comment: Well, if you insist on using this notation (why?) you need to prove this.   I don't see the point, personally.  The usual sentence notation works just fine.

Comment: No, the notation is not mine. I just believe this choice of notation is coherent enough for the purpose of doing some combinatorics :-).

Comment: @lulu The words have been chosen to form a prefix code that allows unambiguous splitting of a run-on sentence into its words. So the recurrence works by parsing from the left, not right. See my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  sure, but it just confuses things.  That's why the OP couldn't do the count for $4$...writing the sentence without any spaces between the words requires the reader to break up every sentence.  And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing $\ baba\ $ and $\ bbbb\ $.

Comment: oh yes, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

There are really $11$ sentences on $4$ letters – you forgot $ba.ba$ and $bb.bb$.

As for the actual question, an admissible sentence can be unambiguously broken up into its words by working from the *left*, since the words form a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code). A word on $k$ letters thus either

- begins with $W_1=a$, and removing it produces a sentence on $k-1$ letters
- begins with $W_2=ba$ or $W_3=bb$, and removing the appropriate word produces a sentence on $k-2$ letters

Thus $N(k)=N(k-1)+2N(k-2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof, I reached the same proof as yours.  I was wondering if it’s possible to prove it by induction.